# Linksys WRT1900AC custom domain routing

Tags: networking, router, dns

Can I configured on the router so that `domain-abc.com` maps to a designated public IP?

Currently I can do it by configuring /etc/hosts to map the domain to any public IP on my workstation.

However, I need to be able to configure it on the router level to overwrite the public DNS, so that all the network devices (including mobile devices) on the LAN will be able to resolve `domain-abc.com`

Comment: I am fairly sure the DNS server in the Linksys is not featured enough to add your own entries.  You could replace the firmware with something like dd-wrt which would allow it, or can you run an internal DNS server?

Comment: I was going to say the same thing as @Paul if you wanted to do that you could flash your router [Here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) just copy your router name in and choose your Version. Then you can set it up like this [LocalinternalDNS](http://cybernetnews.com/local-internal-dns-ddwrt/)

Comment: @NetworkKingPin flashing the router seems to be the best solution for me.  However, will I lose my original custom configurations?  What's the benefit of the flashing to dd-wrt that the Linksys factory firmware won't do?

Comment: You will lose your current configurations. But you can set them all back up and more. I will explain it in the answer one moment.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to stand up a DNS server on your network and just use that?

Comment: @prateek61 Isn't it better to just use Google's DNS for better DNS propagation?  This is more of a one-time task for me to test new domains locally before actually switching to the public nameservers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Answer is yes you can Configure a Router to Map a Designated public ip.

Benfits are [Here](https://www.flashrouters.com/ddwrt-router-information)

First you would need to Flash your current router. **DEMO for Functionality is at the Bottom**

Write Down your Configurations if you have any Special ones as you will need to set all that up with DDWRT Once installed.

[image]

Select the web flash Version for initial installation.

**1.** Install through here Login to your Router using the IP.

**2.** click connectivity on the side

**3.** Click Manually Update Firmware Select the .img you downloaded and let the Router update.

**4.** Now Login to the Router Ip will be 192.168.1.1

**5.** You Will be Prompted to make a User Name and Password and Login.

Now set up the router how you had it before.

And follow This guide Below

> So what do you have to change in DD-WRT? Here’s what you need to do:
>
> Go to the Services tab once you’ve logged into the administration interface.
> Find the section labeled **DNSMasq**, and make sure the DNSMasq option is enabled.
> This is the fun part. In the Additional DNSMasq Options box type out your local DNS configurations in the format of one entry per line:
> **address=/machine_or_domain_name/ip_address** – where machine_or_domain_name is what you want to create/change DNS for (e.g. camera.example.com, google.com, intranet) and ip_address is the new IP address you want it to point to.
> Apply the settings to DD-WRT, and you should be all set.
> This is an example of what your DNSMasq settings may look like:

[image]

Also here is a Demo Click to see functionality. [DDWRT-BUILD 16562 Live](https://www.dd-wrt.com/demo/)

So your would look this this **address=/domain-abc.com/ThePublicIP**

*Enjoy your New More Powerful Router.*